# SQL Grouping by sequential occurrences of a value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I have the below table with 2 columns

```
ID     |     Dept 

1      |    A    
2      |    A
3      |    B
4      |    B
5      |    B
6      |    A
```

I want to do a count such that the output should look as the table below.

```
Dept   |     Count

A      |    2    
B      |    3
A      |    1
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I don't understand, why do you want two records for dept A? Dept A has got 3 records in the table.

Comment: What are your attempts so far?

Comment: Can you clarify the output is correct, i.e. should there only be a single result for A which is supposed to have a count of 3. You mention COUNT which is a little misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slightly different to Michael's, same result:

```
with cte1 as (
  select   id,
           dept,
           row_number() over (partition by dept order by id) - 
             row_number() over (order by id) group_num
  from     test),
cte2 as (
  select   dept,
           group_num,
           count(*) c_star,
           max(id) max_id
  from     cte1
  group by dept,
           group_num)
select   dept,
         c_star
from     cte2
order by max_id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff747/1

Comment: I prefer your method because it uses `row_number() over (order by id)` instead of just the `id`, which means it's more robust in case ids aren't sequential or non-integer.

Comment: Cheers -- Yes I was thinking of that as a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, it looks like you're wanting to count sequential records for each department.

You can do this by combining the row number and the ordering Id.

```
create table tblDept (
    id int not null, 
    dept varchar(50)
);

insert into tblDept values (1, 'A');
insert into tblDept values (2, 'A');
insert into tblDept values (3, 'B');
insert into tblDept values (4, 'B');
insert into tblDept values (5, 'B');
insert into tblDept values (6, 'A');

with orderedDepts as (
  select
    dept,
    id,
    row_number() over (partition by dept order by id) - 
      row_number() over (order by id) as rn
  from tblDept
)
select
  dept,
  count(*) as num
from orderedDepts
group by
  dept,
  rn
 order by
   max(id)
```

Gives the output:

```
+------+-----+
| DEPT | NUM |
+------+-----+
| A    |   2 |
| B    |   3 |
| A    |   1 |
+------+-----+
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f19ea/7)**

Comment: Point to be noted that this wont work if there is a gap between two consecutive IDs with same Dept

Comment: @DeepakPawar Updated the answer to cover this case... my initial assumption was probably the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with SQL.  Count counts distinct items, so count in your case would give you a count of `A` and a count of `B`.

You can only count/group by values in the table, not by the order of rows.  Order is not guaranteed in SQL if you don't use an `order by` anyway.

Comment: The order in this case would be the id, probably. I don't think this is impossible, but it does seem quite inconvenient.

Comment: His question is the count() function and how to get what he wants.  He can't.

Comment: The question is "How can you obtain this output", and he thought he could use `COUNT()` to easily obtain the output. The result in itself probably isn't impossible to achieve in SQL.

Answer (score -2):

run this query for this:

```
SELECT Dept, count(*) FROM table_name group By Dept
```

Comment: can you once check the expected output of him